# Trouble updating UINavigationController's Title

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UINavigationController with a UIViewController as the RootViewController.

The view controller cycles through 3 different view controllers (screen) depending on a popover selected. The cycling is working fine. Now I know that the Nav Controller is supposed to update it's title based on the title attribute being set for it's current controller on the stack, but I'm thinking because of how I've got it set up this could be the cause of my issues.

But I don't know how to get around it. I've a few different things but this seemed most correct:

```
iNephroCareAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.navController.navigationItem.title = @"Test Title";
```

I'm trying to set this from one of the view controllers (screens).

Still, nothing. Anyone have any ideas? Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every view controller is pushed rather than adding it's view as subview, then you can use the below line of code in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear of all view controllers

```
self.title = @"Navigation title";
```

Comment: But the view controllers from where I'm trying to set these titles are not pushed on to the stack. They have to be switched in and out in the root view controller.